# How can I get my slideshow to loop?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to loop the slideshow that it gets back to the first image after the last image is displayed.
I made a slideshow div that contains 5 different images, that will fade in and out after an x amount of time, but the looping part is not working for me.
Thanks for any help!

Html:

```
<div id="slideshow2">
    <img class="slider1" src="images/car1.jpg"></img>
    <img class="slider2" src="images/car2.jpg"></img>
    <img class="slider3" src="images/car3.jpg"></img>
    <img class="slider4" src="images/car4.jpg"></img>
    <img class="slider5" src="images/car5.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow2{
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider1, .slider2, .slider3, .slider4, .slider5{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Jquery:

```
    $(".slider1").animate({"opacity":"1"});
    $(".slider2").delay( 1500);
    $(".slider1").animate({"opacity":"0"});
    $(".slider2").animate({"opacity":"1"});
    $(".slider3").delay( 3000);
    $(".slider2").animate({"opacity":"0"});
    $(".slider3").animate({"opacity":"1"});
    $(".slider4").delay( 4500);
    $(".slider3").animate({"opacity":"0"});
    $(".slider4").animate({"opacity":"1"});
    $(".slider5").delay( 6000);
    $(".slider4").animate({"opacity":"0"});
    $(".slider5").animate({"opacity":"1"});
    $(".slider1").delay( 6000);
    $(".slider5").animate({"opacity":"0"});
```

Comment: there isn't any loop present, just a function that has an end point.

Comment: srry edited the code and now it does work (the slideshow) NOT the loop.

Comment: I dont see a loop in your code...

Comment: No thats the whole point of my question I don't know how to make a loop in my slideshow :)

Comment: you just made animation function without a loop see my answer and use a callback to make the function loop through at the end.

Comment: @user3140707 Don't say "The looping part is not working for me" because that makes it sound like you tried to implement a loop and then had trouble with it. That wasn't the case here. You should say "I don't know how to create a loop". Doing this from the start could have saved a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a callback to the function on the last animation

```
$(".slider5").animate({"opacity":"0"}, slideshow);
```

Comment: Thanks alot that did the job perfectly, such an easy thing but I didn't know how to do it.. Tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback on the last slide.

```
$(".slider5").animate({"opacity":"1"}, function(){
    $(".slider5").animate({"opacity":"0"});
    slideshow();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

(or any one of the 15000 slideshow libraries!)

Answer (score 0):

add the function as a callback to the last animate. You should also remove the delays, and at the functions as callbacks to each other like so:

```
function slideshow(){
   $(".slider1").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 1000, function() {
       $(".slider1").animate({"opacity":"0"}, 500);
       $(".slider2").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 1000, function() {
           $(".slider2").animate({"opacity":"0"}, 500);
           $(".slider3").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 1000, function() {
               $(".slider3").animate({"opacity":"0"}, 500);
               $(".slider4").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 1000, function() {
                   $(".slider4").animate({"opacity":"0"}, 500);
                   $(".slider5").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 1000, function() {
                       $(".slider5").animate({"opacity":"0"}, 500);
                       slideshow();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

slideshow();
```

Or just use a slideshow plugin:
http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-slideshow/

Answer (score 0):

[This should work:](http://jsfiddle.net/jTfFT/1/)

It will run the function every 1,5 sec. You can change that on the setInterval

```
setInterval(function() {
    slideshow();
}, 1500);

var currentSlideId = 0;

function slideshow() {
    currentSlide = $("img", "#slideshow2").eq(currentSlideId);

    nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    if( !nextSlide.length )
        nextSlide = $("img", "#slideshow2").eq(0);

    currentSlide.animate({"opacity":"0"}, 500, function() {
        nextSlide.animate({"opacity":"1"}, 500);

        currentSlideId = nextSlide.index();
    });
}
```